# How to capture the output of a php from javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have written few php files which sit in a server. The output of the php would be as follows:

```
172.xx.xx.xx/myphpfile.php?arg="abc"
```

Output

```
{
status: "ok",
result: "asdsdf"
}
```

My requirement is to call this php api (`172.xx.xx.xx/myphpfile.php?arg="abc"`) from my javascript, parse the output and draw a chart in the page. To summarize the following are my doubts.

1. How to call a remote php file from javascript?
2. How to capture the output of a php file in a javascript?

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319928/how-to-get-success-text-in-extjs may help

Answer (score 1):

Remote PHP? Due to the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) you have to write the PHP so it emits [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). (That link also explains how to use it from JS).

Alternatively, and with more limited browser support, use [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) with [XHR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, javascript is client-side and php is server-side. The web servers outputs text to your browser and it doesn't know about server techniques used.

For fetching and manipulating the data, have a look at [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) and [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: You can solve it a thousand ways, jQuery is one common way, I didn't say its the only way.

Comment: For someone like the user who posted this question (completely new to the idea of AJAX), jQuery would be the only learning tool I suggest. It simplifies the ajax process many times over not to mention the increase in cross-browser compatibility. Look at the answer by `Hungry Mind` above. Do you mean to tell me that code is better to start off with? +1 Jonas

Comment: That's a strawman argument. Just because someone considers jQuery to be a poor place to start doesn't mean they think W3Schools is. Both have their flaws, jQuery hides so much of what is going on that users often don't understand basic things like "The callback doesn't get called before a function you put immediately after the call to the ajax method". W3Schools is just a collection of barely working code, full of security problems, thrown at a wall of adverts. I wouldn't recommend either for someone just starting out.

Answer (score 1):

Both can easily be done with javascript (and even easier with jQuery). If your resulting page is in JSON format (which it appears to be), you can simply do..

```
$.getJSON('172.xx.xx.xx/myphpfile.php', 'arg=abc', function(obj){
    alert(obj.status);
});
```

More info: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

**If the API file is not on your server**

If the API is not on the same domain as your page with the JS, you will need to create your own PHP page to read the remote file, and dump its contents locally to the domain.

**getJson.php**

```
die(file_get_contents('172.xx.xx.xx/myphpfile.php?arg='.$_REQUEST['arg']));
```

**JS**

```
$.getJSON('gtJson.php', 'arg=abc', function(obj){
    alert(obj.status);
});
```

Comment: He doesn't **need** to create his own proxy. Since it's his own service he's written, he can easily adapt it work with JSONP instead.

Comment: Point taken. Most of the time I see these questions, the person posing the question is not in a position to change the source API(s).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Ajax.
Avoid the classic method, prefer using a framework like jQuery or ExtJS, it will be easier and cross-browser.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Ajax

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code which I use

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //Global Variables  
    var xmlHttpFP;

    if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {   
        xmlHttpFP = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");     
    }//End if
    else
    {
        xmlHttpFP = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }//End else

    //Function To fetch Data From Server
    function LoadFPSummary()
    {   

        xmlHttpFP.open("GET","172.xx.xx.xx/myphpfile.php?arg='abc'");

        xmlHttpFP.send();
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = xmlHttpFP.responseText;
    }

    xmlHttpFP.send(null);
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use globals. Test for the standard XHR object before looking for the ActiveX version. What on earth does FP stand for?

Comment: @Quentin, FP is my own naming convention, its doesn't belong to any standard, just for my own understanding. And I understand your suggestions I'll consider that when I have to reuse it. Thanks for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is the tool you need.
Read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp).

Comment: No, don't. That article is full of horrible, horrible code with race conditions and SQL injection security holes wide enough to drive Belgium though.

Answer (score -1):

You have to move AJAX technology

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlhttp;
function loadXMLDoc(url,cfunc)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
function myFunction()
{
loadXMLDoc("172.xx.xx.xx/myphpfile.php?arg=abc",function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Get from PHP</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Load</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Keep away from W3Schools. That code is awful. It has race conditions in it! (The only reason it doesn't have SQL injection problems is because it doesn't include any server side code).

Comment: Also, this would be the *worst* way I can think of to teach someone about the basics of AJAX. This code is overwhelming and with the neat 3rd party wrappers they have out there, there's no reason to use `XMLHttpRequest` or `Microsoft.XMLHTTP`